# Ampscript - BuildRowSetFromString with multiple inputs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, xml

I need to convert the following string

```
[{"productName":"Product1","productPrice":100,"deliverByDate":"04/13/2021","giftMessage":{"message":"message1","sender":"me","recipient":"you"}},{"productName":"Product2","productPrice":100,"deliverByDate":"07/26/2021","giftMessage":{"message":"message2","sender":"me","recipient":"you"}}]
```

so that it converts into a row set that I can present as

> ProductName1, ProductPrice1, deliverByDate1, giftMessage[message]1, giftMessage[sender]1, giftMessage[recipient]1
>
> ProductName2, ProductPrice2, deliverByDate2, giftMessage[message]2, giftMessage[sender]2, giftMessage[recipient]2

I played around with maybe changing the colons to "=" to take advantage of QueryParameter but that was messy and unhelpful. I debated using the "," as the delimiter for BuildRowSetFromString but that just broke each section out and also -- unhelpful. I'm wondering if theres someway to use both to break out each section so that I can get say 6 different rowsets for productName, productPrice, etc. I **feel** like i'm just missing something here. Any insights on direction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this will be very difficult to achieve in AMPscript, take a look at SSJS and the ParseJSON function instead: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformUtilityParseJSON.htm

Comment: @zuzannamj thanks! this sent me down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize it was formatted JSON! I used Datasource and it worked like a charm.